# Filtering collisions between particles and bodies in liquidfun

Tags: javascript, jbox2d, liquidfun

I created a functioning JavaScript game using the Box2d framework that LiquidFun provides (and implemented filtering effectively). I understand how to filter using maskBits, categoryBits, and groupIndices.

I've successfully created one particle, but it is colliding with all fixtures. My hope is to filter out some fixtures so that the particle only collides with some fixtures. **What tag is used to handle particle/fixture collisions and filtering?**

The LiquidFun update notes for the 1.0.0 release states *"Added option to call a contact listener or filter on particle / fixture or particle / particle interactions."* However, I can't find where this was done.

Looking through the source code, `b2ContactFilter` seemed appropriate, but that looks to handle collisions between two fixtures. Similarly, `b2ParticleBodyContact`seems pretty appropriate, but I cannot determine how that is supposed to be implemented.